# How to read a textfile from a specified folder?

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to read a text file from a specified path but have this error **The System cannot find the file specified**

This is the code:

```
File file=new File("D:\\Progs\\FinalCS\\Records\\record.txt");
FileReader FileR=new FileReader(file);
Scanner scan=new Scanner(FileR);
```

Comment: This is going to be a duplicate Question. Can you copy the actual file location you're trying to reach?

Comment: open cmd and type `D:\\Progs\\FinalCS\\Records\\record.txt`.what is the output?

Comment: Have a look at the Oracle SE trail, explains file I/O very clearly...https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Comment: @FastSnail D:\\Progs\\FinalCS\\Records\\record.txt is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @ßürgErSteäk can you try it on run window.are you sure this file exist ?

Comment: Well, does the file exist?

Comment: @immibis Yes, im sure it is

Comment: Okay, well, the way to read a text file from a specified folder is by doing exactly what you're already doing. So the most likely problem is that the file doesn't exist. Perhaps you mistyped the path.

Answer (score -1):

```
String uri = "d:\\123.txt"

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(uri);
InputStreamReader isr =new InputStreamReader(fis);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String s;     
while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
  // read line
}
```